# Delay submit only when form validation is submitSuccess

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with JQueryValidator (http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/).

I have function submitsuccess and submiterror, but i want to delay submit when all inputs are correct (submitsuccess). I put this code in document ready but logically it's apply to submiterror too, so if inputs are incorrects it's submit's anyway:

```
 $('#myform').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 2000); // in milliseconds

});
```

How can i do this? I change to this but doesn't work...

```
 $('input,textarea').jqBootstrapValidation(
  {

    submitError: function ($form, event, errors) { 
      $("#myform").effect( "shake" );
      $("#myform").submit(function(e){
    return false;
});
    }
  }
);
$('input,textarea').jqBootstrapValidation(
  {
    submitSuccess: function ($form, event, errors) { 
        var audio = $("audio")[0];
    audio.play();
      $("#myform").hide().html("<span class='modalok glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span><p class='modalsuccessp'>¡Muchas gracias!</p>").fadeIn('slow');
     setTimeout(function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog('close')
      }, 20000)

    }

  });
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are wanting to do this?  It might help us answer the question.

Comment: Because i want to make this, change html content with fadein of the form (if all inputs are valid change content and show Correct!) and stay 2 seconds before close:  $("#myform").hide().html("<span class='modalok glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span><p class='modalsuccessp'>¡Muchas gracias!</p>").fadeIn('slow');
     setTimeout(function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog('close')
      }, 20000) But it's doesn't work because throws the submit immediately and it don't have time to fadein and show another html content.